# Styling ListSelect in aVdin 8

Tags: list, vaadin, styling, vaadin8

Please help to Styling ListSelect in Vaadin, Is it possible to set it up for choosing the first item at the list? Is it possible to set it up the height of the item? I need to set up the size of each items since the list will be use for touch display.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to have the first item selected? Which vaadin version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set it up the height of the item?

Kind of yes. ListSelect adapts to its font size somewhat nicely, so you could do e.g. like this in your Java code:

```
ListSelect select = new ListSelect();
...
select.setStyleName("my-select");
```

And then in your theme define different font styling, e.g.

```
.my-select {
    font: 300 12px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

> Is it possible to set it up for choosing the first item at the list?

listSelect.setValue(item) or listSelect.select(item) programmatically selects the item.

If you do not know which is the first item, you could e.g. use

```
item = listSelect.getDataCommunicator().fetchItemsWithRange(0,1);
```

to get the first item

Comment: Thank you,  the change of size is working, I made my own css plan with parameters. The selection of first item at the list is not working for me, I insert the object to add item. I need to indicate first item at the list during GUI loading.